# Time based event in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, time, unity-game-engine, vuforia

what I want to do is the following:

I got several variables e.g. and when one variable changes in value (from 0 to 1) i want to start a 'time based event'.

```
public int a = 0; 
public int b = 0; 

if (a == 1) 
{
    //"check for two seconds if int b becomes 1 otherwise go back to usual loop"
}

//basically a second if-statement would follow: 

if ( b == 1 within 5 seconds)
{ 
     //"go to next step"
}
```

I realize this is extremely generic, but hopefully you get what I want to do.
If not, I can elaborate.

Thank you for help.

Comment: What you are looking for is called a `Timer`, and there are a few to choose from. Are you periodically checking this variable for a change?

Comment: I see this is for unity. Where is this code actually being run?

Comment: @RonBeyer I think Fruchtzwerf fixed my problem. I will try and get back to you guys!

Comment: @pquest I'm using a timer in one of the Vurforia scripts. The DefaultTrackableEventHandler and a self-written VirtualButtonEventHandler. This makes things a bit harder because of the lack of a void update().

Comment: @JoriVerbeek ok, I just wanted to make sure you weren't trying to hold the main game loop up for that kind of time. That will hang your game

Comment: You can  add void update() if it doesnt exist. And use states to do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Capsule your variables and start a timer if the variables get changed:

```
//initialising
Timer T = new System.Timers.Timer(2000); //Timer with two second interval
aTimer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;

private int a = 0;
public int A
{
  get
  {
    return a;
  }
  set
  {
    if (value == 1)
    {
      T.Start();
    }
    a = value;
  }
}

private void TimerElapsed(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  //timer elapsed code
  T.Stop();
}
```

if you change the value of your variable A, the timer gets startet if the new values is 1. After the Timer is elapsed it stops.

Comment: I think this is what I need! I will try later today, not able to try it out now:)

Comment: great - feel free to ask :-)